# How to expand text in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

to begin, I'm not really a programmer. I'm helping my aunt with her website because she can't fix one thing and she doesn't have money to pay a programmer. I know You don't have time to read the whole story but basically, this is life or death matter.

The goal is to make a list (which already exist) expandable by on-click
To fix this problem I've spent around 100 hours of work but couldn't find the solution.

(The words are in Polish so be aware of not-understanding xd)

[image: before clicking on it]

[image: expnding after clicking]

I've succeded to make it using html in mysql database 
[image: bad solution]
but it's really trash!!!

The goal is to make it expandable in php to change database to look like this :

[image: database from different partof website]
things in column 2 are shown when you click in title from column 1

Code for this is

```
     $zapytanie = "SELECT id, tytul FROM kafle WHERE kategoria='$kategoria' ORDER by id";
     $wykonaj = mysql_query($zapytanie);
     while($q = mysql_fetch_array($wykonaj))
     {
         $kafel_id = $q['id'];
         $kafel_tytul = $q['tytul'];
         if($kafel_id == $id)
         {
           $menu .= '  <div class="menu_open">
                       <h2>'.nowrap($kafel_tytul).'</h2>
                       ';

           $menu .= '</div>';
           $kafle .= '<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="kafel2" onclick="window.location.href='."'".'view.php?id='.$kafel_id."'".'"><span>'.$kafel_tytul.'</span></div></div>';
         }
         else
         {
           $menu .= '  <div class="menu_hidden"><a href="?id='.$kafel_id.'"><h2 class="kolor-tekst">'.$kafel_tytul.'</h2></a></div>';
           $kafle .= ' <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="kafel" onclick="window.location.href='."'".'view.php?id='.$kafel_id."'".'"><span>'.$kafel_tytul.'</span></div></div>';
         }

     }


    $kafle = '<div class="row">'.$kafle.'</div>';
```

I'm trying to copy "type of database" to use it on different sub-domain

Comment: Could you use something like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/ ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify.The more we understand, the better we can help. I guess you have a series of articles, each with `id`, title, subtitle, and text. I guess, when the user clicks on a title, you want to **reveal** the text and **conceal** the subtitle, but not display a new page. Is that correct?  You're already using Bootstrap, so you may want the so-called "collapsible" bootstrap component. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/  ... and, if you are storing Javascript in columns of your database, you are definitely on the wrong track.

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259320/expanding-tree-in-mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding tree in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259320/expanding-tree-in-mysql)

Comment: O.Jones that is exactly what I'm trying to do, it is done in one part of the website with articles but I'm trying to do the same in the bibliography